# how to display uploaded picture . php ,mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

hey guys i am stuck at very end point of my code , my aim was to Store image path to database and store the image to a directory. and than i want to show those images. 
i am successfully done uploading part but now i am stuck how can i show those images on my webpage, here is my code

```
<?php 
  $sql    = "SELECT * FROM pictures";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $data   = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $image_path=$row["folder_name"];
   $image_name=$row["picture_name"];

   echo "img src=".$image_path."/".$image_name." width=100 height=100";
  }
?>
```

Comment: your html markup is invalid

Comment: write the whole relative path, not juste the directory. Let me explain : IF this folder is one step bellow your current file, source of image will be `../folder_name/image_name`.
Plus you might want to put some tag so it looks like `echo <img src="....." />`

Comment: I'm voting this as a typo.

Comment: I take it that you don't know what I meant by my *"your html markup is invalid"*. Your syntax for the image is wrong. If you had retained the syntax from a tutorial on HTML markup, then maybe you'd not have made that mistake in the first place, and in turn possibly avoiding the post. I deliberately did not show you what the syntax was, because I wanting *"you"* to figure it out by yourself. That way, you'd of learned something.

Comment: yes  @Zyigh sir first i tried  by writing whole <img src="uploads/image.jpg "> i am getting my image ,but i have 10 different images  so how can i show them in a loop?

Comment: Sir @Fred-ii- i really appreciate bu i was trying to figure out since couple of hours and after that i came here   , i tired proper img tag <img src="uploads/image.jpg "> and  i got my image but i just want a proper syntax so that it will work in loop , because i have more than 10 images .

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` => `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` then, given  your new comment to someone else.

Comment: `$data   = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);` you're not using that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fetch associative arrays, use fetch_assoc instead, your $data is not needed here, it's simpler at the end. Also, only select the fields you need in your query. To fix your problem, You are simply missing the HTML , try this:

```
<?php 
  $sql    = "SELECT folder_name, picture_name FROM pictures";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if(!$result) {
      die("Error with your Query: " . mysqli_error($conn));
  }
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $image_path = $row["folder_name"];
      $image_name = $row["picture_name"];
      echo "<img src=\"" . $image_path . "/" . $image_name . "\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\"></img>\n";
  }
?>
```

Comment: OMG it worked xD ... thank you so much sir , you are a life saver,

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: but one thing i didnt get is use of  /  and  "  and use of  \n , can you please clear my doubt.

Comment: the \ before the " is called an escape character, this is used to add special characters in a string, in this case, double quotes, at the end the string looks like this:
<img src="thepath/theimagename" width="100" height="100"></img>

then the \n is called a newline. This jumps the code to a new line to make it clearer to read in a browser "display web page source" type of options.